# How to efficiently calculate huge amount of data by concurrence programming

Tags: c#, asynchronous, concurrency, parallel-processing

**My Goal:** calculate huge amount of time series data. On input I have timerange which is related with some data (In PI System). I have been calculating aggregate functions like Average, Min, Max etc. for certain timespan (in my case It is a day span). So typical synchronous algorithm takes aproximately 30 seconds. But I need  that **some results** have to be shown under 3 seconds. So for example I want to first calculate and shown data from the first 2 months and calculations of the rest of data could be calculated meanwhile.
**What I have tried so far** I have learned that there are a few types of concurrence programming. My questions is which of these method (multi-threading, asynchronous program., Parallel program. etc) would be the best solution. On this link https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/concurrency-in-c/9781491906675/ch01.html I find that asynchronous is mostly for operation without CPU-bound. But of course calculating of aggregated functions is CPU-bound operation. Neverthless my boss told me that I should use asynchronous aprroach. Im not sure if this is the best solution.
 I make asynchronous algorithm using async and wait keyword. Bud then I find out that there are more then one approach. We can use a delegate with various asynchronous software pattern like EndInvoke pattern,WaitHandler etc. (http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=634). 
So basically my question is which of these concurrence techniques should I use fot the best performance. I am aware that this is realy general question but I would like here some your suggestions or maybe ideas about this subject.
Thank you very much for your helps

Comment: First, can your algorithm irrelevant to parallelism produce such "partial results" data? Also, this has nothing to do with performance. The point of using parallelism for performance is to reduce total time it takes to compute something, not having partial results shown while the algorithm is running.

Comment: Maybe performance is not the correct word.I need reduce total time but also I have to be able show some partial results imediately. If I use traditional synchronous algorithm I can produce partial results of course but I supposed to use asynchronous or concurrence aprroach generally. But thanks for advice

Answer (score 0):

If you already possess the data and you know what type of aggregation you want to use (sample rate), you should pre-aggregate the data. This way you don't have to calculate the aggregate every time, but already have the aggregate present.

> “The single most dramatic way to affect performance in a large data warehouse is to provide a proper set of aggregate (summary) records that coexist with the primary base records. Aggregates can have a very significant effect on performance, in some cases speeding queries by a factor of one hundred or even one thousand. No other means exist to harvest such spectacular gains.” – Ralph Kimball, 1995

Answer (score -1):

You can start multiple tasks one by one not waiting for the result of previous tasks. On final statement wait for all tasks to be completed. Here is a Sample [Task example](http://dotnetcodr.com/2014/03/04/waiting-for-a-group-of-tasks-to-complete-in-net-c/)
.

Comment: Answers which rely on external information are generally frowned upon on SO. Please edit the important information from the linked page into your answer.